# Программное создание TableLayout и кнопка под ним. Как сделать, чтобы кнопка была видна?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-tablayout

В фрагменте программно создается табличка, которая вставляется в TableLayout - xml ниже.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/files"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="send" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Однако кнопка почему-то не показывается, как будто она скрывается под табличкой. Как сделать, чтобы кнопка (и другие элементы под такой программно создаваемой табличкой) были видны?

Answer (score 1):

Можно выделить кнопку в отдельный лэйаут, например так:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="16dp"
android:id="@+id/view"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/files"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="70"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

И назначить 2-м LinearLayout веса: "android:layout_weight" в разметке.
В моем примере 10 и 70 соответственно.
Тогда кнопка будет независимой от всех остальных элементов))

Comment: спасибо, вы натолкнули меня на правильную мысль).